# Удаление дубликатов в java

Tags: java

Всем доброго времени суток.

Задача простая, но что-то никак не могу её реализовать, так как в java я новичок, но разобраться в решении очень хочется и интересно. Заранее спасибо неравнодушным.

Задана последовательность, состоящая от 1 до 20 слов, между которыми находится не менее 1 пропуска. Каждое слово содержит от 1 до 10 символов. Напечатать эту же последовательность слов, но без повторений одинаковых слов.

Comment: [http:/tsya.ru](http:/tsya.ru)? [http:/tsya.ru](http:/tsya.ru).

Comment: @argamidon, это называется человек не поленился отредактировать свои грамматические ошибки, за что я ему проставил плюс.

Answer (score 3):

```
/*
  Создаём массив слов
*/
String[] mWords = new String[] { "вот", "тут", "слова", "слова" };

/*
  Создаём список строк без повторений
*/
HashSet<String> mSet = new HashSet<String>();

/*
  Копируем данные из массива в список, убирая дубликаты
*/
Collections.addAll(mSet, mArray);

/*
  Выводим результат
*/
for (String word : mSet)
{
    System.out.println(word);
}
```

---

**Update**

Большое спасибо @zhenyab за замечание о сохранении последовательности!
Если важна последовательность, то решение доступно на [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19511797/remove-duplicates-in-an-array-without-changing-order-of-elements). Там массив чисел, но не составит особого труда переделать под строки.

Comment: Нужно сохранить последовательность! Set не пойдет. OrderedMap я думаю будет в самый раз!

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Суть вроде ясна, что радует) Но не работает структура данных hash-set. Не подскажете библиотеку для нее?

Comment: @zhenyab OrderedMap ? чтото я неслышал о таком. LinkedHashSet наверняка то, что надо.

Comment: @Іра Івасько Если ты думаешь что понимаешь, и спрашиваешь где достать HashSet, то это значит что ты ничего не понимаешь.

`import java.util.* ` добавь

Comment: хорошо) спс)

Comment: @argamidon [OrderedMap][1]
[1]:https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/OrderedMap.html

Comment: можно ли применять такой способ если слова вводить пользователь из клавиатуры? и они кидаються в чаровой массив?